# Php Symfony framework culture URL

Tags: php, symfony1

I need to create different URL for different cultures.

Example: 
localhost/trips   should be localhost/matkat in finish culture ,

but localhost/trips must be not available in finish culture.

Tried such configuration in routing.yml but no success

destination_en:
  url:   /trips
  param: { module: destination, action: index }
  requirements: { sf_culture: en  }

Comment: Two questions: how many URLs will you have roughly? And how are you generating the URL "slugs" (e.g. matkat, trips, etc)... are these dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

There's a an i18n routing plugin in the Symfony plugins repo: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/zxI18nRoutingPlugin